# how Convert Jquery Variable to C# Variable in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a MVC Appliction. I want to know, Is it possible that we get values from server Model by javascript in our views?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnInsert').click(function () {

        var **id** = $(this).attr("id");

        var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model[**id**]));

    });
});
```

Comment: what is `Model[..]`?

Comment: wouldnt it have to be `@Html.Raw(Model[Json.Encode(**id**)]);`

Comment: C# is rendered on server and Jquery on client.

Comment: No, because `Model` (or any other MVC/Razor objects) does not exist by the time any JavaScript is running on the client side.

Comment: It's not true @Andrew. Model is a list of Person that I post to my view. I have access to Model because it redered when my view loaded. but I cannot access to Model[id]. because id is jquery variable.

Comment: No its not possible. `@Html.Raw()` is razor code which is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Your `id` variable is a client side javascript variable and does not event exist at that point - its not in scope. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: yes.it's not possible. thanks Stephen Muecke

Comment: If you want to access `C#` variable in `Javascript` you can use syntax `@:js_variable`

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid mixing C# with Javascript... It is definitely not a good practice.

What happens if you move your javascript code to a separate file?

There is a simple workaround. Use hidden fields and get them by javascript. For example:

Html

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHiddenValue" value="@Model[**id**]" />
```

JS

```
var model = $('#myHiddenValue').val();
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Do you want to post a javascript variable to controller?

Comment: Is it possible to convert jquery variable to c# variable in Jquery? such this: var id = $("#id").val();                                                                                  @{ int a = id}

Comment: It is not possible, because c# runs on server, javascript runs on client. However, there are some workarounds. Why do you need to convert js to c#?

Answer (score 0):

No, because Model (or any other MVC/Razor objects) does not exist by the time any JavaScript is running on the client side.